# how to connect javascript code to python flask

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, flask, web-development-server

Iam working on a front end project.
my requirement is I need to create a flask API.

In front end one java script file will be there from there **signal/message should go to python flask api** and **flask API should also return signal/message to JavaScript**

Ex: in front end one button will be there, if i click that button message should go to flask api like "local_filename.txt" then python flask should read that message and should reply/responded with the content in that "local_filename.txt"

Iam not very much in to Web development, please help me guys
please post any sample code in both python and JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

An attempt on your part to solve the task would have been desirable and useful. This platform is not a service where you can let others program it for you, but rather an aid should you run into problems in your attempts.
Nevertheless and exceptionally in the following my example.

The requested file is identified on the server using a [variable rule](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#variable-rules) and sent via [send_from_directory](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.send_from_directory).
The respective text document should be in the "files" folder of your project. In the example, according to your specifications, a document with the name "local_filename.txt" is expected.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/download/<path:filename>')
def download(filename):
    return send_from_directory(
        'files',
        filename,
        as_attachment=True
    )
```

In order to react to clicks on the button, all necessary buttons are requested and an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) is registered for them. With a click, the [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) of the button is requested and the required url is generated. In doing so, it is taken into account that this is a valid form.
The request of the method type GET is made by asynchronous Javascript (AJAX) using the [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) command. The transmitted data is received as a [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob). The content is extracted and displayed. There is no consideration of HTML specific characters.

The template called "index.html" should be in the "templates" folder of your project.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button data-source="local_filename.txt">Retrieve</button>
    <output id="result"></output>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function(){
        let elems = document.querySelectorAll("button[data-source]")
        elems.forEach(elem => {
          elem.addEventListener('click', event => {
            const url = `/download/${encodeURIComponent(elem.dataset.source)}`;
            fetch(url)
              .then(resp => resp.blob())
              .then(blob => {
                blob.text().then(text => {
                  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = text;
                });
              })
              .catch(err => console.error("Error", err));
          });
        });
      })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would be pleased if your requirements are met by this example and would ask you to follow the rules and procedures of this service in the future.

Have fun and success in implementing your project.